# AWS Athena: cross account write of CTAS query result

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, permissions, acl, amazon-athena

I have big historical dataset in an **account A**. This dataset is in csv format and partitioned by `year/month/day/hour/`. My goal is to convert this data to parquet, with additional normalisation steps and extra level of partitioning, e.g. `year/month/day/hour/product/`, and write it back to the **same bucket of the account A** under `processed/` "directory". So "directory" tree would look like

```
S3_bucket_Account_A

dataset
|
├── raw
│   ├── year=2017
|   │   ├── month=01
|   |   │   ├── day=01
|   │   |   |   ├── hour=00
|   │   |   |   └── hour=01
|                                 
├── processed
│   ├── year=2017
|   │   ├── month=01
|   |   │   ├── day=01
|   |   |   │   ├── hour=00
|   |   │   |   |   ├── product=A
|   |   │   |   |   └── product=B
|   |   |   │   ├── hour=01
|   |   │   |   |   ├── product=A
|   |   │   |   |   └── product=B
```

In order to do that, I am sending CTAS query statements to Athena with boto3 API. I am aware of [limitations of CTAS queries](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/considerations-ctas.html), e.g. can write in up to 100 partitions within the same query, location of CTAS query result must be empty/unique. So, I process one raw partition at the time and content of CTAS query is being generated on a fly taking those limitation in consideration.

Since I am using **account B** to execute these CTAS queries, but result of these queries should be written into S3 bucket **owned by account A**. I have been given the following permissions which are specified at the Bucket policy level of account A.

```
{
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Principal": {
        "AWS": "__ARN_OF_ACCOUNT_B__"
    },
    "Action": [
        "s3:*"
    ],
    "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::dataset",
        "arn:aws:s3:::dataset/*"
    ]
}
```

**The problem is that account A (bucket owner) doesn't have access to the files that have been written as a result of CTAS query executed by Athena of account B**.

As I understand, there is an option of account A creating an IAM role for me, and then I would perform this task as if I were account A. But unfortunately, this options is out of the question.

I have found ways on how to transfer ownership/change ACL of S3 objects. One way would be to output CTAS query result in S3 bucket of account B and then copy these files to bucket of account A ([original source](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-bucket-owner-access/))

```sh
aws s3 cp s3://source_awsexamplebucket/ s3://destination_awsexamplebucket/ --acl bucket-owner-full-control --recursive
```

Another way is recursively update acl with something like ([original source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50610430/6147064))

```sh
aws s3 ls s3://bucket/path/ --recursive | awk '{cmd="aws s3api put-object-acl --acl bucket-owner-full-control --bucket bucket --key "$4; system(cmd)}'
```

But these two options would require additional `GET` and `PUT` requests to S3, thus more money to pay for AWS. But more importantly, I update AWS Glue table (destination table) of **account A** with partitions from the created table after CTAS query succeeded. In this way, IAM users in **account A** can start query transformed data straight away. Here is a general idea of how I update destination_table

```py
response = glue_client.get_partitions(
    CatalogId="__ACCOUNT_B_ID__",
    DatabaseName="some_database_in_account_B",
    TableName="ctas_table"
)

for partition in response["Partitions"]:
    for key in ["DatabaseName", "TableName", "CreationTime"]:
        partition.pop(key)
        
glue_client.batch_create_partition(
    CatalogId="__ACCOUNT_A_ID__",
    DatabaseName="some_database_in_account_A",
    TableName="destination_table",
    PartitionInputList=response["Partitions"]
)
```

I do it in this way instead of `MSCK REPAIR TABLE destination_table` because the latter takes takes long time for some reason. So as you can see, if I opt for use of `aws s3 cp` I would also need to take that into account when I copy meta information about partitions

**So my real question is how can I grant full control to the owner of the bucket within CTAS query executed by another account?**

#### Update 2019-06-25:

Just found [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56572459/how-to-ensure-that-athena-result-s3-object-with-bucket-owner-full-control), but it seems that they use IAM role which is not an option for my case

#### Update 2019-06-27

I found out that: 1) It is not possible to change ACL within CTAS query. Instead, an S3 object can be copied on itself (thanks to comments from [John Rotenstein](https://stackoverflow.com/users/174777/john-rotenstein) and [Theo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1109/theo)) with a new ownership.

#### Update 2019-06-30

Just to recap. I run CTAS query from `account B` but result is saved in a bucket owned by `account A`. This is how CTAS query "header" looks like:

```sql
CREATE TABLE some_database_in_account_B.ctas_table
WITH (
  format = 'PARQUET',
  external_location = 's3://__destination_bucket_in_Account_A__/__CTAS_prefix__/',
  partitioned_by = ARRAY['year', 'month', 'day', 'hour', 'product']
) AS (
    ...
    ...
)
```

Since I use `boto3` to submit CTAS queries and I know `__destination_bucket_in_Account_A__` together with `__CTAS_prefix__`, then instead of copying files on themselves with `aws cp` I can directly change their ACL within the same python script upon successful execution of CTAS query.

```py
s3_resource = aws_session.resource('s3')
destination_bucket = s3_resource.Bucket(name="__destination_bucket_in_Account_A__")

for obj in destination_bucket.objects.filter(Prefix="__CTAS_prefix__"):
    object_acl = s3_resource.ObjectAcl(destination_bucket.name, obj.key)
    object_acl.put(
        ACL='bucket-owner-full-control'
    )
```

**Note**, since I need to submit a number CTAS queries which exceeds the limitation of AWS Athena, I already have implemented logic that automatically submits new queries and performs some additional things, e.g. updating destination Glue table and logging. Therefore, including these lines of code is quite straight forward.

Comment: Well, decent number of options in the question itself. However, if it is that the data copied by CTAS to accountA's bucket is being continuosly accessed by some querying service (like hive or athena etc.) using AccountA's roles, then I may have to go for the first solution here to avoid any 'Access Denied' errors while the object's acl property is being corrected..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, the only way to do this cleanly is to use an IAM role in account A with a trust policy that allows account B to assume the role. You mention that this is not possible for your case, which is unfortunate. The reason why it's currently not possible any other way is that Athena will not write files with the "bucket-owner-full-control" option, so account A will never fully own any files created by an action initiated by a role in account B.

Since the policy you have been granted in the destination bucket permits everything, one thing you can do is run a task after the CTAS operation finishes that lists the objects created and copies each one to itself (same source and destination keys) with the "bucket-owner-full-control" ACL option. Copying an object like this is a common way to change storage and ACL properties of S3 objects. This will, as you say, incur additional charges, but they will be minuscule in comparison to the CTAS charges, and charges related to future queries against the data.

The real downside is having to write something to run after the CTAS operation, and coordinating that. I suggest looking at Step Functions to do it, you can make quite nice workflows that automate Athena and that cost very little to run. I have applications that do more or less exactly what you're trying to do that use Step Functions, Lambda, and Athena and cost pennies (I use IAM roles for the cross account work, though).

Comment: I needed things to run after CTAS query, so I have already implement some logic to orchestrate those tasks. Now, instead of copying each file on itself, I directly changes its' ACL (see updated post). Ideally, I would like to use S3 batch operations job (one by one seems slow), but couldn't find how it could be setup and run with `boto3` instead of AWS console.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you perform the copy.

The "additional GET and PUT requests" would be minor:

- GET is $0.0004 per 1,000 requests
- PUT is $0.005 per 1,000 requests

Alternatively, you run a `aws s3 cp --recursive` command from Account B to copy the files to themselves (yes!) with a change of ownership (it also needs another change, like setting metadata to be accepted as a copy command). This is similar to what you were proposing with `put-object-acl`.

Comment: Yes, this option would be the last resort. Additional price (approx 15$) is actually not that big of an issue. I have updated post to reflect why I don't really want to go with this option.

Comment: You have 300 million objects?

Comment: No, should be around 3 million. Isn't there a single `PUT` request for each object? If that is the case then 1 million of `PUT` requests costs 5$. => 3 million 15$.

Comment: Oops! I had my dollars and cents confused. Still, 3 million objects is quite a lot! Are you sure you need that many levels of partition? How many files, and how many MB, are the files in a given hour? It might be better to stop at `day` and concatenate the files.

Comment: Atm, there are 125-175 objects totaling in 200 - 300 MB with around 40 partitions within a given hour. We did consider stopping at different levels e.g. `year/month/day/product` or `year/month/day/hour`, but during preliminary runs compression wasn't as good. Also due to nature and frequecy of future queries, we decided to have 5 partition levels for cost efficiency.

Comment: The cost efficiency will only be if a query has a `WHERE` statement with _all levels_ specified: year, month, day, hour, product. Is that typical in your queries? If you are worried about the number of objects, then using fewer levels and larger files would reduce the number of requests. You could also consider converting the data into Parquet or ORC if you don't already do that. It will reduce the amount of data that Athena needs to read, which will again reduce costs.

Comment: 1. Yes, all levels will be specified in `WHERE` because it is generated from template 2. Data is written into Parquet but even with this format Athena scannes more data