# Unable to view results in S3 bucket after executing Athena query in different account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, permissions, account, amazon-s3

I have two accounts: Account A and Account B.

I'm executing an Athena query in Account A and want to have the query results populated in an S3 bucket in Account B.

I've tested the script that does this countless times within a singular account so know that there is no issues with my code. The query history in Athena also indicates that my code has ran successfully, so it must be a permissions issue.

I'm able to see an object containing a CSV file with the query results in Account B (as expected) but for some reason cannot open or download it to view the contents. When I attempt to do so, I only see XML code that says:

```
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
```

Within the file properties, I see `Unknown Error` under `Server-side encryption settings` and `You don't have permission to get object ACL` with a message about not having allowed the `s3:GetObjectAcl` action.

I've tried to give both Account A and Account B full S3 permissions as follows via the bucket policy in Account B:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "This is for Account A",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::iam-number-account-a:root"
      },
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-name",
        "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-name/*"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Sid": "This is for Account B",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::iam-number-account-b:root"
      },
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-name",
        "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-name/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Some other bucket (Account B) configuration settings that may be contributing to my issue:

- Default encryption: Disabled
- Block public access: Off for everything
- Object ownership: Bucket owner preferred
- Access control list:

Bucket Owner - Account B: Objects (List, Write), Bucket ACL (Read, Write)

External Account - Account A: Objects (Write), Bucket ACL (Write)

If anyone can help identify my issue and what I need to fix, that'd be greatly appreciated. I've been struggling to find a solution for this for a few hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common problem when creating objects in an Amazon S3 bucket belonging to a different AWS Account is that the object 'owner' remains the original Account. When copying objects in Amazon S3, this can be resolved by specifying `ACL=bucket-owner-full-control`.

However, this probably isn't possible when creating the file with Amazon Athena.

See other similar StackOverflow questions:

- [How to ensure that Athena result S3 object with bucket-owner-full-control - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56572459/how-to-ensure-that-athena-result-s3-object-with-bucket-owner-full-control)
- [AWS Athena: cross account write of CTAS query result - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56758783/aws-athena-cross-account-write-of-ctas-query-result)

A few workarounds might be:

- Write to an S3 bucket in Account A and use a Bucket Policy to grant Read access to Account B, *or*
- Write to an S3 bucket in Account A and have S3 trigger an AWS Lambda function that copies the object to the bucket in Account B, while specifying `ACL=bucket-owner-full-control`, *or*
- Grant access to the source data to an IAM User or Role in Account B, and run the Athena query from Account B, so that it is Account B writing to the 'output' bucket

Answer (score 0):

CTAS queries have the `bucket-owner-full-control` ACL by default for cross-account writes via Athena